# Syntax error when i try to insert into table

Tags: mysql, syntax, sql-insert

## My Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contas` (
  `cod_conta` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cod_char` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(180) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(180) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(180) NOT NULL,
  `datacc` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `adm` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cod_conta`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET
```

## Insert SQL

```
> INSERT INTO 'contas'('cod_char','username','password','email') VALUES (2,'sdgsd','186672cc13','aaa')
```

## Error

> 1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de
>   ''contas'('cod_char','username','password','email') VALUES

Comment: You are using single quotes where you don't need any quotes at all.  If you have to use quotes, use back ticks.  I vote to close this type of question as a simple typographical error.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: Also read where backticks required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use quotes between columns name and table name

**Modified query:**

```
INSERT INTO `contas`
(cod_char,username,password,email) VALUES (2,'sdgsd','186672cc13','aaa')
```

You can use `backticks` between columns and table name as I use in table name.

**Side note**:

As my other mate mentioned in comments it may be typo error, I suggest you to read where you need to use `backticks`.